# GTree from Glib example

Tags: c, data-structures, glib

So i have a struct that goes like this:

```
typedef struct sales
{
    int* salesN;
    int* salesP;
}*Sales;
```

And i will have many strings like char* product that i want to associate to this struct. And the struct GTree from Glib seems like a good option in terms of efficiency.

Basically I want the key to be the string and the value to be the struct. I also want them to be sorted alphabetically so i'm guessing the compare function should be something along the lines of strcmp.

But i'm having trouble starting and initialising the GTree. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a quick code example of how to initialise, how to insert and how to search and modify some values.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to fix your struct declaration. It's `typedef <type declaration> <name>`. So not `*Sales` but just `Sales`.

```
typedef struct sales
{
    int* salesN;
    int* salesP;
} Sales;
```

Now we follow the instructions in [the GTree documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.64/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html), first we make a tree and tell it how to compare keys.

```
GTree *sales_tree = g_tree_new(g_str_equal);
```

We can't use `strcmp` because it has the wrong signature. Instead we use the functions found in [Hash Tables](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-str-equal).

Now we make a Sale and insert it with a key. This is all done with pointers, keys and values.

```
// Make a Sale
int n = 23;
int p = 42;
Sales sale = { .salesN = &n, .salesP = &p };

// Insert it as "The Stuff".
const char *key = "The Stuff";
g_tree_insert(sales_tree, &key, &sale);
```

And we can retrieve it, as a pointer, using the same key.

```
Sales *found = g_tree_lookup(sales_tree, key);
printf("n %d, p %d\n", *found->salesN, *found->salesP);
```

And, finally, clean up the tree to avoid leaking memory.

```
g_tree_destroy(sales_tree);
```

---

`g_tree_foreach` works very similar to `q_sort_r`. It takes a function pointer of type [`GTraverseFunc`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.64/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#GTraverseFunc) which will be called on each node. If it returns true, the traversal stops.

`g_tree_foreach` takes an extra argument which will be passed to each call of the function. This allows you to store information during the traversal without having to use global variables.

For example, here's a little function which uses a [GPtrArray](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.64/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html#g-ptr-array-free) to collect a list of all the values in the tree.

```
gboolean find_all_nodes(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer all) {
    g_ptr_array_add(all, value);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Then we traverse the tree using our function like so.

```
GPtrArray *all = g_ptr_array_new();
g_tree_foreach(sales_tree, find_all_nodes, all);
```

And we can look at what we captured in the pointer array, being sure to free it once we're done with it.

```
    for( int i = 0; i < all->len; i++ ) {
        Sales *s = g_ptr_array_index(all, i);
        printf("n %d, p %d\n", *s->salesN, *s->salesP);
    }
    g_ptr_array_free(all, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more thing. I don't quite understand the function foreach of the GTree documentation.
void g_tree_foreach (GTree *tree,
                                  GTraverseFunc func,
                                  gpointer user_data);

Let's say i wish to traverse the trees in order to sum up all the sales from every product. I don't understand what the second and thirds parameter should be

Comment: @J.Gomes It's very similar to `qsort_r`. `tree` is the tree. `func` is a function pointer with the signature of [`GTraverseFunc`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.64/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#GTraverseFunc). `user_data` is an extra data of your choice. The `func` will be called on each node with its key, value, and your user_data. If it returns true, the traversal stops. You can use `user_data` to collect nodes. I'll add an example.